# nginx: [emerg] invalid host in upstream "wordpress:/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default:26

Tags: mysql, wordpress, nginx, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am beginner and need some answers.

I always get invalid host in upstream, how can I fix it? Help pls.

### **docker-compose.yaml**

```
version: '3.7'

services:
    db:  
      image: mysql:8.0
      container_name: db
      restart: always
      networks:
        - app-network  
    wordpress:
      build: ./requirements/wordpress/
      depends_on: 
          - db
      container_name: wordpress
      restart: always
      networks:
        - app-network
    nginx:
      build: ./requirements/nginx/
      depends_on:
        - wordpress
      container_name: nginx
      restart: always
      ports:
          - 443:443
      networks:
          - app-network

networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge
```

Here I tried to build 3 services mysql, wordpress and nginx.

### **dockerfile for nginx**

```
FROM debian:buster

RUN apt-get -y update

RUN apt-get -y upgrade

RUN apt-get install -y nginx vim procps openssl net-tools php-gd php-xml

COPY ./nginx.conf /etc/nginx/sites-available/default

RUN mkdir -p /etc/ssl/private

RUN chmod 700 /etc/ssl/private

RUN openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -subj "/C=RF/ST=London/L=London/O=innoaca/OU=student/CN=rusya" -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout /etc/ssl/nginx-selfsigned.key -out /etc/ssl/nginx-selfsigned.crt;

CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

In dockerfile for nginx I just installed it.

### **nginx.conf**

```
   server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        listen [::]:443 ssl;
        server_name localhost;
        
        ssl on;

        ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/nginx-selfsigned.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/nginx-selfsigned.key;
        
        ssl_protocols TLSv1.3;

        root /var/www/html;
        index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =405;
        }
  
        location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                fastcgi_pass wordpress:/run/php/php7.3-fpm.sock;
        }
}
```

Here I tried to use socket, I need that nginx and worpress communicate on 9000 port.

### **dockerfile for wordpress**

```
FROM debian:buster

RUN apt-get -y update

RUN apt-get -y upgrade

RUN apt-get -y install vim wget nginx php-cli php-fpm php-mysql php-json php-opcache php-mbstring php-xml php-gd php-curl mariadb-server

WORKDIR /var/www/html/

RUN wget https://wordpress.org/latest.tar.gz

RUN tar -xvzf latest.tar.gz

RUN rm -rf latest.tar.gz

COPY ./wp-config.php ./wordpress/

RUN chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/wordpress

RUN chmod -R 755 /var/www/html/wordpress

RUN sed -i '36 s/\/run\/php\/php7.3-fpm.sock/9000/' /etc/php/7.3/fpm/pool.d/www.conf

CMD ["/usr/sbin/php-fpm7.3", "daemon off"]
```

In dockerfile for wordpress I changed "listen = /var/run/fastcgi.sock" to "listen = 9000" in /etc/php/7.3/fpm/pool.d/www.conf.

I am not sure in last string "CMD ["/usr/sbin/php-fpm7.3", "daemon off"]", but hope that its wright, I wanted that the container would be always up, but I could make a mistake.

Comment: You need to specify hostname and TCP port in `fastcgi_pass` directive, you can't use socket path since your PHP-FPM daemon run in different container: `fastcgi_pass wordpress:9000;`

Comment: @IvanShatsky thanks, the error is fixed. Could you explain me about daemon, what does it do and PHP-FPM Daemon runs in only unix?